# Unable to get a DirectionalLight shadow to update correctly

Tags: three.js

I have a `DirectionalLight` in my scene. When I first create the light the shadow covers the intended area. When the viewport is resized (canvas size) I update the shadowCamera parameters (right,left,top,bottom), and the light's position and target, but the shadow only covers the area before the update.

What flag do I have to set to get the shadow properly updated to reflect the new settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the pattern you need to follow to update a shadow camera on-the-fly:

```
light.shadowCameraLeft = -100;
light.shadowCameraRight = 100;

light.shadowCamera.left = light.shadowCameraLeft;
light.shadowCamera.right = light.shadowCameraRight;

...

light.shadowCamera.updateProjectionMatrix();
```

three.js r.64