# How to update shadowMap size of light in THREE.js

Tags: three.js, shadow

I want to be able to update the size of the shadow map on a directional light in three.js.

When simply updating the the "shadowMapWidth" and "shadowMapHeight", nothing happens. When I update the "shadowMapSize" manually, the shadow sort of changes resolution but is not rendered properly since the shadowmap rendertarget is not set to the correct resolution. And finally, when I update the shadowmap rendertarget width and height, the shadow disappears completely (and or gets positioned incorrectly).

If anyone has any experience changing the shadowmap resolution of a shadow light in three.js I would love some help on getting this to work.

Comment: See if this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031120/unable-to-get-a-directionallight-shadow-to-update-correctly

Comment: That answer seems to only address updating the camera. The camera in my example is not changing, only the rendertarget resolution. There doesn't seem to be an "updateMatix" function on WebglRenderTargets so I am just unsure of how to update it accordingly.

Comment: I am able to get it to work by completely replacing the webglrendertarget with a cloned one that has a different width/height, but that seems to cause performance issues.

Comment: You can change the width of the shadow map as described in the link I referenced. Do not try to change the resolution. three.js supports cascading shadow maps -- maybe that is what you want.

Comment: I want to change the resolution so that the "quality" of the rendering can be changed dynamically. But if I have to reinitialize the rendertarget to do that then I guess it is okay. If I dispose() of the old one then the performance degradation seems to be negligible.

Answer (score 2):

You have to dispose of the shadow map for it to update. Try this:

```
light.shadowMapWidth = 4096;
light.shadowMapHeight = 4096;
light.shadowMap.dispose();
light.shadowMap = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
// initialize
this.light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 2);
this.light.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
this.light.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;
this.light.shadow.camera.near = 0.1;
this.light.shadow.camera.far = 5000;
this.light.shadow.bias = 0.00001;
this.light.shadow.autoUpdate = true;

// update
this.light.shadow.dispose();
this.light.shadow = null;
this.light.shadow = new DirectionalLightShadow();
this.light.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024*4;
this.light.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024*4;
this.light.shadow.camera.near = 0.1;
this.light.shadow.camera.far = 5000;
this.light.shadow.bias = 0.00001;
this.light.shadow.autoUpdate = true;
```

You need to import

> three/src/lights/DirectionalLightShadow.js