# How to dynamically update the resolution of the Shadow Map in THREE.js when changing resolution?

Tags: three.js, shadow, shadow-mapping

I want to dynamically change the resolution of the shadows of a spotlight in THREE.js.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031120/unable-to-get-a-directionallight-shadow-to-update-correctly) question first seems relevant but it is not about my issue. I change the parameters of shadowmap dynamically but this is not affecting the scene. Even when I add more mesh objects after this, it does not affect the shadows in the scene/light. When I use an initial value (256,256), it is applied but not after showing the scene.

```
light.shadowMapWidth = 2048; 
light.shadowMapHeight = 2048;
```

I tries the following but it didn't work:

```
light.shadowMap.setSize(100,100)
```

When I change the light.position, the shadow is updated but the resultion is not updated. It seems to use the .shadowMapWidth property in the beginning during the initialisation only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to dynamically update the resolution of a shadow map, you can use this pattern:

```
light.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
light.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;
light.shadow.map.dispose(); // important
light.shadow.map = null;
```

three.js r.74